# Replay rosbags recorded with --split option

Tags: ros, rosbag, play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have recorded number of rosbags using --split option, say "file_0.bag", "file_1.bag", "file_2.bag" and so on to build a map. My question is: how to play them back one after the other. Using `$ rosbag play file_0.bag file_1.bag file_2.bag` plays all files at the same time. Whereas, I want to play one after another.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190461/replay-rosbags-recorded-with---split-option/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-08-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you load 3 sequential bag files recorded with --split they will playback according to the timestamps that they were received. So although they will actually be playing back simultaneously. At any given timestep data will only come from one of the bags.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-08-18**:
Thanks! I was (embarrassingly) oblivious of timestamps when I thought of the problem.

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2014-08-19**:
Thanks Tully. It works. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

UPDATE: Tully's answer is the correct way of doing it, also because (after thinking more about my suggestion) the command below would result in a lag between playing one bag and starting to play the next one (lag which, from my experience, varies according to the size of the bag).

---

AFAIK, rosbag does not implement such a feature.

However, you can easily take advantage of the Linux shell by running the following command:

`$ rosbag play file_0.bag && rosbag play file_1.bag && rosbag play file_3.bag`

The result will be a sequential execution of those 3 commands, provided the previous finished execution successfully.
If you do not care about whether the previous command finished successfully, replace '&&' with ';'.

See [this link](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists) for more info.

---

Originally posted by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) with karma: 806 on 2014-08-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2014-08-18**:
Thanks Murilo :)